# Pandas: cannot convert object to datetime

Tags: python, pandas

This is my DataFrame:

```
               dt_object      Lng
1    2020-01-01 00:00:00  1.57423
2    2020-01-01 01:00:00  1.57444
3    2020-01-01 02:00:00  1.57465
4    2020-01-01 03:00:00  1.57486
5    2020-01-01 04:00:00  1.57506
```

dt_object prepared with python classic datetime function.
But

```
print (df.columns)
```

gives me:

> Index(['dt_object', 'Lng'], dtype='object'),

so they both are object types.

I try:

```
df_candles['dt_object'] = df_candles['dt_object'].astype('datetime64')
```

but it doesn't help.

It is still object.
How can i convert this column to pandas 'datetime64'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that you'd convert it using the [to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) function

```
df_candles['dt_object'] = pd.to_datetime(df_candles['dt_object'])
```

note that if you want, you can also specify the format of your string object as

```
df_candles['dt_object'] = pd.to_datetime(df_candles['dt_object'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

also check
https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes

Comment: I tried this but i get AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'to_datetime'

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(some_series)`.

Comment: @IgorK. apologies, I wrote it wrong, just fixed it

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
df_candles['dt_object'] = pd.to_datetime(df_candles['dt_object'])
```

When You are try to check column types use:

```
df.dtypes
```

instead of:

```
df.columns
```